# Ошибка при обращении к элементу списка

Tags: python, парсер

При попытке присвоить в переменную данные из элемента списка получаю ошибку `IndexError: list index out of range`. Ошибка в функции `get_content()`

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 28, in <module> main() 
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 25, in main get_content(get_html(url)) 
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 16, in get_content name = td_list[0] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Вывожу принтом тип данных - список длинной в  4 элемента,а при обращении по индексу ошибка.
В чем может быть проблема ?

```
# парсер товаров с xxx
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_content(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    trcont = soup.findAll('tr')
    for tr in trcont:
        td_list = [t.text for t in tr.findAll('td')] # чтобы обратиться к каждому элементу cоздал список 
        print(type(td_list))
        print(len(td_list))
        name = td_list[0]
        description = td_list[1]
        proizvoditel = td_list[2]




def main():
    url = 'xxx'
    get_content(get_html(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки полностью.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 25, in main
    get_content(get_html(url))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\abracadabra\irbis.py", line 16, in get_content
    name = td_list[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверять результат поиска элементов. У вас в `td_list` пустой список.

Скорее всего, у вас первый `<tr>` имеет `<th>`, поэтому поиск `<td>` не был успешным.

Сделайте так:

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    trcont = soup.findAll('tr')
    for tr in trcont:
        td_list = [t.text for t in tr.findAll('td')]

        # Если список пустой, пропускаем обработку текущего <tr>
        if not td_list:
            continue

        print(type(td_list))
        print(len(td_list))
        name = td_list[0]
        description = td_list[1]
        proizvoditel = td_list[2]
```